# how can i design simple application

Tags: utility

how can i design simple dot sisx application to track public transport on nokia symbian s60v3 phone

Answer (score 1):

With [Symbian](http://developer.symbian.org/) [development tools](http://www.palowireless.com/symbian_epoc/devtools.asp).

Comment: Shortest and most useful answer ever.